# Meteor: account login link takes time to load

Tags: performance, meteor

I have started a meteor application using the accounts packages for facebook, twitter, github and auth accounts. For UI, I am using the bootstrap package. Whenevee I load my site [projectx.meteor.com](http://projectx.meteor.com), the login links take some time

I have everything static on the HTML page, except for the link to login:

**client/x.html:**

```
<div class="masthead">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">{{loginButtons}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There is no JS on the client side and I have called the startup method on the server.
**Server/startup.js:**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

});
```

Also, when I visit the above URL from IE 9 on my Windows Phone 7.5, it doesn't show the login link at all.

**Update:** After the comment below, I modified my code to remove packages and additional HTML. The packages now included are:

- preserve-inputs
- accounts-ui
- accounts-password
- accounts-facebook
- accounts-twitter
- accounts-github

I have removed bootstrap and the only thing on my template now is {{loginButtons}}, It still loads the login link after a delay. Is this the default behavior of the accounts package ?

Comment: did you try to put {{loginButtons}} outside <a></a> <li></li>? i know that those tags may be important to boostrap but try it without them to see.


I highly doubt that bootstrap is the problem, but since you have no js code....

Comment: @mohamedmellouki Updated the question with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the buttons take so long to load is because Meteor has to ask the server-side for the necessary configuration information (located in a collection in your Mongo instance) before it can render the login buttons for each of the external services you want to use. I think the best solution (and the solution I use) is to simply build the buttons client-side if you want faster results or tweak the login buttons template to allow for data ported in from the client-side using a JSON object with all the OAuth keys it needs.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, this is the default behavior.
There is no problem about bootstrap or js in your code. 
I cant explain exactly why but it works that way.

Comment: From an answer to a question about using Meteor in production, on a different website(http://www.quora.com/Meteor-web-framework/Is-Meteor-good-enough-to-use-in-production), it was stated that:

There is no server side rendering. When a user hits a meteor app, Meteor converts all template data into javascript and then sends it to the client. This also means slower client side loads, atleast initially. That said, because this is a single page app, after the initial load, everything should be snappy.